# Adapter "holding on" to view when I animate it

Tags: android, gridview, android-listview, android-arrayadapter

I'm using a custom adapter for a GridView, and feeding it an ArrayList of my custom data class.

The idea is, when the user presses (+) on an item, its number goes up, and when they press (-), it goes down.

This has worked perfect with the following code:

Activity:

```
//playerLayouts is the ArrayList of my Player class.
playerLayouts.get(position).changeLife(-1); //All this does is decrement life by 1.
adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

Adapter:

```
holder.textLife = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.player.text_life);
...
holder.textLife.setText(Integer.toString(player.life));
```

So this works great. I press plus, it goes up, I press minus, it goes down. All is well.

But, if I want to put a little "-1" popup in the view that shows that 1 has been subtracted, and I animate the view, a problem arises.

```
...
//textLifeChange is a different TextView in the layout. Also, I'm using NineOldAndroids.
textLifeChange.setText(Integer.toString(player.lifeChange));
animate(holder.textLifeChange).setDuration(2000).alpha(0); //There are a few more animations in addition to this one.
```

Basically, whenever the animation is playing (which is a full two seconds), the view doesn't do any more updates.

For example, say "life" = 20. I hit (-), and now it says 19, and my little popup shows "-1" and fades out. Then, just ONE second later, I hit (-1) again. Nothing happens. The "life" TextView still says 19, and the popup just keeps playing its animation with no change. So I wait another second, and the animation is finished. NOW if I press (-) again, it updates properly again.

Interestingly, if I log my `setText` method, I see that *it is* updating with the correct number, and `getView` is being called, but it's just.. not updating visibly.

What's wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I daresay that your animation is  hogging UI Thread,  and thus prevents changes in other parts of interface.   This asnwer shoud help you:

[Android: Running thread preventing animation from starting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7289295/android-running-thread-preventing-animation-from-starting)